# Loop through all Excel files starting with "vip" in Folder and run another Macro

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I have done many loops before, but for some reason, this one doesn't work. I want to find all the Excel files in a folder that begin with "vip" and run another macro. That second macro does many things and saves the file in another folder (hence why when the loop ends, I kill all the remaining files).

The issue is when I run the loop, the first files is found, the second macro is run, but when it loops, it can't find the second file. I did a version with a counter but that didn't really work. The counter could find the three files I needed to run the macro on, but the same issue happened when starting the loop for the second macro, it would find the first file, and the second would not be found. I even tried a version that opened all Excel files in a loop, using a IF statement to find which ones to run the macro on and which to simply close, but I ran into the exact same issue as the other two versions.

So basically, it finds the first file, does what it has to, loops and then gives me the Error 1004 message, where the folder might have been moved, renamed or deleted. I'm stumped.

Thanks for your help!

Here is my code (sorry for the French statements, but you should understand what the code does anyway!):

```
' Loop_pour_importation_Zoho
'
'Bloquer mise-à-jour visuelle
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
'Bloquer les alertes
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
'Loop pour mise en page de tous les fichiers Excel
    Dim VIP As String
    Dim Folder As String
    Dim Compte As Integer
    Dim CompteLoop As Integer
    
    Folder = "C:\Users\Raid\Desktop\RAID\Test\importation\"
    VIP = Dir(Folder & "vip*.xls*")

    Do While Len(VIP) > 0
        With Workbooks.Open(Folder & VIP)
            Call Module20.Mise_en_forme_Zoho
        End With
        VIP = Dir
    Loop

'Effacer les fichiers originaux
     Kill "C:\Users\Raid\Desktop\RAID\Test\importation\*.xls*"

'Réactiver mise-à-jour visuelle
    Application.ScreenUpdating = Vrai
    
'Réactiver les alertes
    Application.DisplayAlerts = Vrai

End Sub
```

```
Sub Mise_en_forme_Zoho()
'
' Mise_en_forme_Zoho Macro
'

'Nommer les variables

    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim Dossier As String
    Dim Document As String
    Dim RapportTraid As Workbook
    Dim Fichier As String
    Dim Liste As Workbook
    Dim DernLigne As Integer
    Dim ProchLigne As Integer
    Dim NextRow As Integer
    Dim Infos As Integer
    Dim CodeTel As Workbook
    Dim LigneFin As Integer
    Dim LigneSuite As Integer
        
'Définir le rapport à modifier

    Dossier = "C:\Users\Raid\Desktop\RAID\Test\importation\"
    Fichier = Dir(Dossier & "vip*.xls")
    
    Set Liste = Workbooks.Open(Dossier & Fichier)

'Compteur de lignes à partir de la colonne 1

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'Insérer et nommer les nouvelles colonnes

    Columns("A:S").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Source"
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "code tel"
    Range("C1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Phone"
    Range("D1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Lead Status"
    Range("E1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "start_date"
    Range("F1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "end_date"
    Range("G1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Offers"
    Range("H1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Concessionnaire"
    Range("I1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Semaine"
    Range("J1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Event Date"
    Range("K1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Email"
    Range("L1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Brand/Marque"
    Range("M1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Model/Modèle"
    Range("N1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Year/Année"
    Range("O1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "KM"
    Range("P1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "marque"
    Range("Q1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "model"
    Range("R1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "année"
    Range("S1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Last Name"
    
'Remplir les informations de base
    
    For i = 2 To LastRow
    
        Cells(i, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "VP"
        Cells(i, 4).Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Imported"
        Cells(i, 3).Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[24]"
        Cells(i, 11).Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[22]"
        Cells(i, 16).Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[18]"
        Cells(i, 17).Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[18]"
        Cells(i, 18).Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[18]"
        Cells(i, 19).Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[6]&"" ""&RC[7]"
    
    Next i
    
'Ouvrir le rapport traid
    
    Range("U2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    
    Document = Dir(Dossier & "traid*.xls")
    
    Set RapportTraid = Workbooks.Open(Dossier & Document)
    
'Compter les lignes du rapport à partir de la ligne 1

    DernLigne = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ProchLigne = DernLigne + 1
    
'Trouver la ligne correspondant à l'événement

    Range("A" & ProchLigne).Activate
    Range("A" & ProchLigne).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    For i = 2 To DernLigne
    
        If Cells(i, 3).Value = Range("A" & ProchLigne) Then
            Range("A" & i & ":S" & i).Copy
            Liste.Activate
            NextRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
            Worksheets("vip").Activate
            Range("A" & NextRow & ":S" & NextRow).Activate
            Worksheets("vip").Select
            Range("A" & NextRow & ":S" & NextRow).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
        End If
        
    Next i

'Remplir les information du rapport Traid

    Infos = LastRow + 1
    
    For i = 2 To LastRow
    
        Cells(i, 5).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = Cells(Infos, 8)
        Cells(i, 7).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = Cells(Infos, 13)
        Cells(i, 8).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = Cells(Infos, 7)
    
    Next i

'Séparer le début et la fin de l'événement

    Columns("E:E").Select
    Selection.Replace What:=" ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("E1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
        :="/", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
        
'Remplir le numéro de la semaine

    Range("I2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=ISOWEEKNUM(RC[-4])"
    
'Trouver le jour de la semaine

    Range("T" & Infos).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=WEEKDAY(R2C[-15])"
    Range("U" & Infos).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=WEEKDAY(R2C[-16])+1"
    Range("V" & Infos).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=WEEKDAY(R2C[-16])"

'Changer le jour en nom

    Range("T52:V52").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Selection.Replace What:="1", Replacement:="Sunday", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
    Selection.Replace What:="2", Replacement:="Monday", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
    Selection.Replace What:="3", Replacement:="Tuesday", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
    Selection.Replace What:="4", Replacement:="Wednesday", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
    Selection.Replace What:="5", Replacement:="Thursday", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
    Selection.Replace What:="6", Replacement:="Friday", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
    Selection.Replace What:="7", Replacement:="Saturday", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2

'Rentrer les jours dans Event Date

    Range("J" & Infos & ":J" & Infos).Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("J52"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
        :=Chr(10), FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

    Range("J3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R" & Infos & "C[10]&RIGHT(R" & Infos & "C,LEN(R" & Infos & "C)-5)"
    Range("J4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R" & Infos & "C[11]&RIGHT(R" & Infos & "C[1],LEN(R" & Infos & "C[1])-5)"
    Range("J5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R" & Infos & "C[12]&RIGHT(R" & Infos & "C[2],LEN(R" & Infos & "C[2])-5)"
    Range("J2").Select
    ActiveCell.Value = Range("J3") & Chr(10) & Range("J4") & Chr(10) & Range("J5")

'Compléter les infos dans toutes les lignes

    For i = 3 To LastRow
        
        Cells(i, 9).Value = Cells(2, 9).Value
        Cells(i, 10).Value = Cells(2, 10).Value
    
    Next i
    
'Mise en forme générale

    Range("F1").Value = "end_date"
    
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    
'Supprimer la ligne du rapport Traid dans Liste

    Rows(Infos).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    
'Supprimer le numéro de campagne du rapport Traid et fermer

    RapportTraid.Activate
    Rows(ProchLigne).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    
'Copier le nom du concessionnaire

    Liste.Activate
    Range("H2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    
'Ouvrir le rapport code de téléphonie

    Set CodeTel = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Raid\Desktop\RAID\Test\Macro TRaid\Code Tel.xlsx")
    CodeTel.Activate
    
'Compter les lignes de Code Tel à partir de la ligne 1

    LigneFin = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LigneSuite = LigneFin + 1
    
'Trouver la ligne correspondant au concessionnaire

    Range("A" & LigneSuite).Activate
    Range("A" & LigneSuite).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    
    For i = 1 To LigneFin
    
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = Range("A" & LigneSuite) Then
            Range("B" & i).Copy
        End If
        
    Next i
    
    Liste.Activate
    Worksheets("vip").Activate
    Range("B2").Activate
    Worksheets("vip").Select
    Range("B2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

'Fermer Code Tel

    CodeTel.Activate
    Rows(LigneSuite).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    
'Remplir Liste avec Code Tel

    Liste.Activate
    Worksheets("vip").Activate
    
    For i = 3 To LastRow
        Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(2, 2).Value
    Next i
    
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
    
'Sauvegarder, fermer et supprimer Liste

    ChDir "C:\Users\Raid\Desktop\RAID\Test\vers Zoho\"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    Fichier, FileFormat:=xlExcel8, _
        Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, _
        CreateBackup:=False
    Liste.Close
        
End Sub
```

Comment: What happens in `Mise_en_forme_Zoho` ?

Comment: @TimWilliams A ton of stuff. It opens the "vip" Excel file, adds columns, fills some of them with info already in the file and fills the rest with info from two seperate Excel files (one in "Folder" and one somewhere else that doesn't move). Then is saves the file and closes it. The code is too long to paste here.

Comment: Do you use `Dir()` in that method?  If you comment out that `Call` line does your code open each of the workbooks in the folder?   You say it "opens the file" but the file is already open?

Comment: @TimWilliams No, Mise_en_forme_Zoho doesn't open the VIP files, only the loop does. Mise_en_forme_Zoho opens an Excel report in the same Folder as the VIP files, which is defined within that module, and closes it once it's done with it. It also opens a reference Excel file, defined within the module, and closes it once it's done. Mise_en_forme_Zoho closes the VIP file, though, should I not do that?

Comment: @TimWilliams In Mise_en_forme_Zoho, I don't use Dir(). I define directories to call the different files I need, but I don't Loop or anything like that.

Comment: I don't see any obvious issues with your posted code.  Maybe try CDP1802's suggestion below.

Comment: There is a Dir in Mise_en_forme_Zoho on 2nd line `Fichier = Dir(Dossier & "vip*.xls")`. `Set Liste = Workbooks.Open(Dossier & Fichier)` will make the first file found active and the active workbook you entered the sub with will be lost. I think the problem is now clear however the fix will take some work.

Comment: If I used the same names as in the Loop macro, without using a new Dir, would it work? Basically, start off the Mise_en_forme_Zoho with Liste=Workbooks.Open(Folder & VIP)? Or Set Liste = ActiveWorkbook?

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: You cannot nest calls to Dir() (you must complete one loop before starting another).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, there are probably some things that are defined for no reason in there because I didn't make a pass to clean it up, but after the answers I was given, I went and defined my documents differently so there wouldn't be a Dir with the loop and it works!

Thanks a lot!

Here are the macros now:

```
Sub Loop_pour_importation_Zoho()
'
' Loop_pour_importation_Zoho
'

'Bloquer mise-à-jour visuelle

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
'Bloquer les alertes

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
'Définir les variables

    Dim Folder As String
    Dim traid As String
    Dim rapport As Workbook
    Dim VIP As Variant
    
'Ouvrir le rapport traid

    Folder = "C:\Users\Raid\Desktop\RAID\Test\importation\"
    traid = Dir(Folder & "traid*.xls")
    
    Set rapport = Workbooks.Open(Folder & traid)
    
'Loop pour mettre en forme tous les fichiers Excel
    
    VIP = Dir(Folder & "vip*.xls*")
    
    Do While Len(VIP) > 0
    
        Set Clients = Workbooks.Open(Folder & VIP)
        Clients.Activate
    
        With ActiveWorkbook
            Call Module5.Mise_en_forme_Zoho
        End With
        
    VIP = Dir
        
    Loop
    
'Fermer rapport traid

    rapport.Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    
'Effacer les fichiers originaux

     Kill "C:\Users\Raid\Desktop\RAID\Test\importation\*.xls*"

'Réactiver mise-à-jour visuelle

    Application.ScreenUpdating = Vrai
    
'Réactiver les alertes

    Application.DisplayAlerts = Vrai
    
'Message de fin

    MsgBox ("La mise en forme pour l'importation vers Zoho est complétée !")

End Sub
```

```
Sub Mise_en_forme_Zoho()
'
' Mise_en_forme_Zoho Macro
'

'Nommer les variables

    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim Dossier As String
    Dim Fichier As String
    Dim Liste As Workbook
    Dim Document As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim RapportTraid As Workbook
    Dim DernLigne As Integer
    Dim ProchLigne As Integer
    Dim NextRow As Integer
    Dim CodeTel As Workbook
    Dim Infos As Integer
    Dim LigneFin As Integer
    Dim LigneSuite As Integer
    Dim Save As String
    Dim DateDébut As String
    Dim DateFin As String
        
'Définir le rapport à modifier
    
    Set Liste = ActiveWorkbook
    Fichier = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Save = Left(Fichier, Len(Fichier) - 4)

'Compteur de lignes à partir de la colonne 1

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'Insérer et nommer les nouvelles colonnes

    Columns("A:S").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Source"
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "code tel"
    Range("C1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Phone"
    Range("D1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Lead Status"
    Range("E1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "start_date"
    Range("F1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "end_date"
    Range("G1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Offers"
    Range("H1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Concessionnaire"
    Range("I1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Semaine"
    Range("J1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Event Date"
    Range("K1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Email"
    Range("L1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Brand/Marque"
    Range("M1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Model/Modèle"
    Range("N1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Year/Année"
    Range("O1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "KM"
    Range("P1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "marque"
    Range("Q1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "model"
    Range("R1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "année"
    Range("S1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Last Name"
    Range("AH1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Trade-in Brand/Marque de l'échange"
    Range("AI1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Trade-in Model/Modèle de l'échange"
    Range("AJ1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Trade-in Year/Année de l'échange"

    
'Remplir les informations de base
    
    For i = 2 To LastRow
    
        Cells(i, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "VP"
        Cells(i, 4).Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Imported"
        Cells(i, 11).Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[22]"
        Cells(i, 16).Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[18]"
        Cells(i, 17).Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[18]"
        Cells(i, 18).Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[18]"
        Cells(i, 19).Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[6]&"" ""&RC[7]"
    
    Next i
    
'Ouvrir le rapport traid
    
    Range("U2").Select
    Selection.Copy
            
    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
    
        If wb.Name Like "traid*" Then
            Set RapportTraid = wb
        End If
        
    Next
    
    RapportTraid.Activate
    
'Compter les lignes du rapport à partir de la ligne 1

    DernLigne = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ProchLigne = DernLigne + 1
    
'Trouver la ligne correspondant à l'événement

    Range("A" & ProchLigne).Activate
    Range("A" & ProchLigne).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    For i = 2 To DernLigne
    
        If Cells(i, 3).Value = Range("A" & ProchLigne) Then
            Range("A" & i & ":S" & i).Copy
            Liste.Activate
            NextRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
            Worksheets("vip").Activate
            Range("A" & NextRow & ":S" & NextRow).Activate
            Worksheets("vip").Select
            Range("A" & NextRow & ":S" & NextRow).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
        End If
        
    Next i

'Remplir les information du rapport Traid

    Infos = LastRow + 1
    
    For i = 2 To LastRow
    
        Cells(i, 5).Value = Cells(Infos, 8)
        Cells(i, 7).Value = Cells(Infos, 13)
    
    Next i
        
'Séparer le début et la fin de l'événement

    Columns("E:E").Select
    Selection.Replace What:=" ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("E1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
        :="/", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
        
'Remplir le numéro de la semaine

    Range("I2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=ISOWEEKNUM(RC[-4])"
    
'Trouver le jour de la semaine

    Range("T" & Infos).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=WEEKDAY(R2C[-15])"
    Range("U" & Infos).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=WEEKDAY(R2C[-16])+1"
    Range("V" & Infos).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=WEEKDAY(R2C[-16])"

'Changer le jour en nom

    Range("T" & Infos & ":V" & Infos).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    
    If Range("E" & Infos).Value = "en" Then
    
        Selection.Replace What:="1", Replacement:="Sunday", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
        Selection.Replace What:="2", Replacement:="Monday", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
        Selection.Replace What:="3", Replacement:="Tuesday", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
        Selection.Replace What:="4", Replacement:="Wednesday", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
        Selection.Replace What:="5", Replacement:="Thursday", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
        Selection.Replace What:="6", Replacement:="Friday", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
        Selection.Replace What:="7", Replacement:="Saturday", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
            Else:
        Selection.Replace What:="1", Replacement:="Dimanche", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
        Selection.Replace What:="2", Replacement:="Lundi", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
        Selection.Replace What:="3", Replacement:="Mardi", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
        Selection.Replace What:="4", Replacement:="Mercredi", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
        Selection.Replace What:="5", Replacement:="Jeudi", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
        Selection.Replace What:="6", Replacement:="Vendredi", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
        Selection.Replace What:="7", Replacement:="Samedi", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
    
    End If

'Rentrer les jours dans Event Date

    Range("J" & Infos & ":J" & Infos).Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("J" & Infos), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
        :=Chr(10), FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
        
    If Range("E" & Infos).Value = "en" Then

        Range("J3").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R" & Infos & "C[10]&RIGHT(R" & Infos & "C,LEN(R" & Infos & "C)-5)"
        Range("J4").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R" & Infos & "C[11]&RIGHT(R" & Infos & "C[1],LEN(R" & Infos & "C[1])-5)"
        Range("J5").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R" & Infos & "C[12]&RIGHT(R" & Infos & "C[2],LEN(R" & Infos & "C[2])-5)"
        Range("J2").Select
        Else
        Range("J3").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R" & Infos & "C[10]&RIGHT(R" & Infos & "C,LEN(R" & Infos & "C)-6)"
        Range("J4").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R" & Infos & "C[11]&RIGHT(R" & Infos & "C[1],LEN(R" & Infos & "C[1])-6)"
        Range("J5").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R" & Infos & "C[12]&RIGHT(R" & Infos & "C[2],LEN(R" & Infos & "C[2])-6)"
        Range("J2").Select
        
    End If
    
        ActiveCell.Value = Range("J3") & Chr(10) & Range("J4") & Chr(10) & Range("J5")

'Compléter les infos dans toutes les lignes

    For i = 3 To LastRow
        
        Cells(i, 9).Value = Cells(2, 9).Value
        Cells(i, 10).Value = Cells(2, 10).Value
    
    Next i
    
'Mise en forme générale

    Range("F1").Value = "end_date"
    
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    
'Supprimer le numéro de campagne du rapport Traid et fermer

    RapportTraid.Activate
    Rows(ProchLigne).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    
'Copier le nom du concessionnaire

    Liste.Activate
    Range("G" & Infos).Select
    Selection.Copy
    
'Ouvrir le rapport code de téléphonie

    Set CodeTel = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Raid\Desktop\RAID\Test\Macro TRaid\Code Tel.xlsx")
    
    CodeTel.Activate
    
'Compter les lignes de Code Tel à partir de la ligne 1

    LigneFin = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LigneSuite = LigneFin + 1
    
'Trouver la ligne correspondant au concessionnaire

    Range("A" & LigneSuite).Activate
    Range("A" & LigneSuite).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    
    For i = 1 To LigneFin
    
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = Range("A" & LigneSuite) Then
            Range("B" & i).Copy
        End If
        
    Next i
    
    Liste.Activate
    Worksheets("vip").Activate
    Range("B2").Activate
    Worksheets("vip").Select
    Range("B2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

'Fermer Code Tel

    CodeTel.Activate
    Rows(LigneSuite).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    
'Remplir Liste avec Code Tel et concessionnaire

    Liste.Activate
    Worksheets("vip").Activate
    
    For i = 2 To LastRow
    
        Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(2, 2).Value
        Cells(i, 3).Formula = Cells(2, 2).Value & Cells(i, 27)
        Cells(i, 8).Formula = "VIP " & Cells(Infos, 7)
        
    Next i
    
    Columns("B:C").Select
    Columns("B:C").Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Columns("H:H").Select
    Columns("H:H").Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        
'Supprimer la ligne du rapport Traid dans Liste

    Rows(Infos).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        
'Formater les colonnes

    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0"
    
'Séparer les dates en format texte et la réassembler

    Columns("E:F").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
    Rows(Infos).Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "General"

    Range("A" & Infos).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=YEAR(R2C5)"
    Range("B" & Infos).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MONTH(R2C5)"
    Range("C" & Infos).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=DAY(R2C5)"
    Range("D" & Infos).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=RC[-3]&""-""&IF(LEN(RC[-2])=2,RC[-2],""0""&RC[-2])&""-""&IF(LEN(RC[-1])=2,RC[-1],""0""&RC[-1])"
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    
    DateDébut = Range("D" & Infos).Value

    Range("E" & Infos).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=YEAR(R2C6)"
    Range("F" & Infos).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MONTH(R2C6)"
    Range("G" & Infos).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=DAY(R2C6)"
    Range("H" & Infos).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=RC[-3]&""-""&IF(LEN(RC[-2])=2,RC[-2],""0""&RC[-2])&""-""&IF(LEN(RC[-1])=2,RC[-1],""0""&RC[-1])"
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        
    DateFin = Range("H" & Infos).Value
        
    For i = 2 To LastRow
    
        Cells(i, 5).Value = DateDébut
        Cells(i, 6).Value = DateFin
        
    Next i
    
    Columns("E:F").Select
    Columns("E:F").Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
    
    Rows(Infos).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    
'Sauvegarder, fermer et supprimer Liste

    ChDir "C:\Users\Raid\Desktop\RAID\Test\vers Zoho\"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    Save & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSVUTF8, _
        Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, _
        CreateBackup:=False
    Liste.Close
        
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try moving your subroutine call outside the `Dir` loop.Also pass filename to sub.

```vb
    Folder = "C:\Users\Raid\Desktop\RAID\Test\importation\"
    VIP = Dir(Folder & "*.xls*")
    
    Dim myfiles As New Collection
    Do While Len(VIP) > 0
        myfiles.Add VIP
        VIP = Dir
    Loop

    For Each VIP In myfiles
        Call Module20.Mise_en_forme_Zoho(Folder & VIP)
    Next
```

Modify sub to use parameter

```vb
Sub Mise_en_forme_Zoho(filename as string)

     ' Dims
     Dossier = "C:\Users\Raid\Desktop\RAID\Test\importation\"
     ' Fichier = Dir(Dossier & "vip*.xls")
     Set Liste = Workbooks.Open(filename)
```

Comment: It's not working... I had an error since VIP is a string instead of an object, so the "For each" wouldn't work. I changed VIP for Workbook in myfiles and File in myfiles, and I have the same Error 1004.

Comment: @thierry Dir returns a string ( a filename ) so that is what you should declare VIP  as. What error did you get ?

Comment: Compilation error. Control variable for For Each must be of the variant or object type (might not be exactly that since I had to translate it). That is why I tried Workbook in myfiles and File in myfiles. That repaired the error but returned the same Error 1004 as my original problem.

Comment: @thierry Sorry my mistake, declare VIP as variant.

Comment: The first file was done correctly, then the second and third were opened but Module 20 didn't run, so it lead to a problem when came the time to kill the original files (since Module 20 closes them at the end).

Comment: @thierry In that case the problem is most likely in the sub and in particular relying on the active workbook.I would suggest moving the workbooks.open into the sub and pass the filename as a parameter.`Call Module20.Mise_en_forme_Zoho(Folder & VIP)`

Comment: I added Module20.Mise_en_forme_Zoho to my question, I couldn't get your suggestion to work.